# function declaration error, "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token"

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I'm getting an error on line 4:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
```

I'm pretty weak at this point when it comes to functions, so I know that there is something wrong with my function declaration(?). Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
shapeDetermine (char letter);

int main()
{ 
    char letter;
    int  side, area, base, height; // lengths to be used in calculating area

    cout << "Enter the first letter of the shape:"; 
    cin>> letter;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Added:

```
void shapeDetermine (char shape)            
{
    int  side, area, base, height; // lengths to be used in calculating area
    if (letter == 's')              //determine what shape is used - square
    {
           cout<< " Enter the length of side of square:";
           cin>> side;
           area = side * side;    // formula for area of square
           cout<< " The area of the square is "<< area<< " cm."<<endl;
    }
    else if (letter =='t')        // triangle
    { 
        cout<< " Enter the height of triangle:";
        cin>> height;
        cout<< " Enter length of base of triangle:"<< endl;
        cin>> base;
        area = (base * height) / 2;   // formula for area of triangle
        cout<< " The area of the triangle is "<< area<< " cm."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<" Invalid shape entered."<< endl;  // for any character other than s||t
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not declaring a return type for `shapeDetermine`.  If for example it is supposed to return an int, it should be declared:

```
int shapeDetermine(char letter);
```

**Updating** to respond to the new code the OP posted:

That new code is fine.  However, if it appears **after** `main()` in the file (or in another file) then you still need to declare a function prototype for it before you call it.  Given the function definition you've posted, the prototype would be:

```
void shapeDetermine(char shape);
```

**Another update** to address the comments:

You need to actually call the function.  In your as-posted code for `main()` you aren't calling `shapeDetermine()` anywhere.  Try changing your `main()` to read like this:

```
cout << "Enter the first letter of the shape:"; 
cin>> letter;
shapeDetermine(letter);
system ("pause");
```

Comment: int main()
{ 
    char letter, shape;
    cout<< "Enter the first letter of the shape:"; 
    cin>> letter;
    system ("pause");
return 0;
}

Comment: I'm still not getting the results that I am looking for. Essentially, this programs purpose is to ask for a letter, s or t, corresponding to square or triangle, and then determine the area of that shape based on the dimensions given. For some reason the program runs and asks for the letter input and then never executes anything after that... I'm pretty confused. Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Mrod - Are you calling the function after taking the input? If called the function, what is `letter` in `shapeDetermine` function ?

Comment: @Mrod -- if your code is that is above, you're **not calling** `shapeDetermine()`.  Right after the `cin` line, add a new line that says `shapeDetermine(letter);`

Comment: letter is the char that the input is assigned to, either s or t.

Comment: Quantum, thank you very much, big help. Everyone else, thank you as well. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the return value of your function (void?)

Comment: I'm going to upload the code in increments, as I have now resolved the prototype issue but the program is not executing the function.

Answer (score 0):

So far I can see you have declared the function shapeDetermine but in its declaration you haven't specified a return type. I think you must specify one even if it is void.